# X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID, PASSWORD and SIGNATURE

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to implement PayPal Adaptive Payments API. Into the headers I should include these informations:

```
headers.put("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID", "tok261_biz_api.abc.com"); 
headers.put("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD","1244612379"); 
headers.put("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE","lkfg9groingghb4uw5" 
headers.put("X-PAYPAL-DEVICE-IPADDRESS", "168.212.226.204"); 
headers.put("X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT", "NV"); 
headers.put("X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT", "NV");  
headers.put("X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID", "APP-80W284485P519543T");
```

I've created test accounts for both, buyer and seller. But I don't really know what are these first three items. I couldn't find that information. There are multiple sites developer.paypal.com, x.com so it's confusing. I don't know which USERID and SIGNATURE should I use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it on developer.paypal.com -> Profile link(on top right)

Answer (score 1):

The @pocoa's answer is not working anymore. You can find Classic API credentials on http://www.paypal.com and navigating `Account` - `Profile` - `My Selling Tools` - `API Access`.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/apiCredentials/

Answer (score 1):

You can find these information at https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts

Click to your relevant Paypal profile and see API CREDENTIALS tab.